# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name android

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I get error when I compile library `fm.jiecao:jiecaovideoplayer:5.7`.

Error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies] /Users/dd/Desktop/test/ddd/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'. 
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'. Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'. 
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 25.061 secs Information:5 errors Information:0 warnings Information:See complete output in console
```

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ccccccup"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 10
        versionName '1.7'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    /*dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode = true
    }*/
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //Optional: see how to use the utility.
    compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })



    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.12'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.3.0@aar'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.3.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary:adjustable-imageview:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.Cutta:TagView:1.3'
    compile 'com.github.douglasjunior:android-simple-tooltip:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
    compile 'fm.jiecao:jiecaovideoplayer:5.7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `compileSdkVersion 23` so you need to use the support libs of api 23

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
```

downgrade `RecyclerView` to 23 or upgrade the `compileSdkVersion` to 25